# How to display "loading" gif instead of wpf controler when loading?

Tags: wpf, xaml, fallback

Consider a `TextBlock` in wpf that is bound asynchronously to a property in the viewmodel where the `get` uses a time consuming method. Using the `Fallback` tag in the xaml code, I can set the `Text` tag of the `TextBlock` to "Loading...".

But I have actually a `ListBox` that is bound to an `IEnumerable<MyType>` where the List box items display different fields of `MyType`. How can I have a laoding gif (or any kind of different wpf element) displayed while the bounded `IEnumerable<MyType>` is being loaded ?

I guess that I could bind the `Visibility` of the Loading element to some kind of a `bool` that describes the state of the asynchronous property, but I don't find such a bool in xaml. If it does not exists in xaml, I could work out the state of the loading method and create this `bool` in the viewmodel. Would that be the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read @Stephen Cleary's article about patterns for asynchronous MVVM applications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx.

You could bind to a `NotifyTaskCompletion<IEnumerable<MyType>>` source property and use a `DataTrigger` or a simple binding to the `IsNotCompleted` property to display an `Image` until the `Result` property has been set:

```
<!-- Busy indicator -->
<Image Source="pic.png" Visibility="{Binding YourItemsSourceProperty.IsNotCompleted,
            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<!-- Results -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSourceProperty.Result}" Visibility="{Binding
          UrlByteCount.IsSuccessfullyCompleted, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Please read the article for more information about do's and don'ts.

Comment: Thanks for the link mm8, the article is very interesting. I inspired myself from it to work out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the state of `ItemsSource`, you could change the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsSource" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                                <Image Source="LoadingImage.png"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer grek40. Do you mean that `Value="{x:Null}"` is the tag that controls the "not loaded yet" feature of the bounded property ?

Comment: Yes, in this example I assume the `ItemsSource` would be `null` until it is loaded. However, you can always use the same principal approach with `DataTrigger` and a `Converter` to support arbitrary complex decision mechanisms or base the decision on some different property like `ItemsLoaded` from the viewmodel.